# NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to return an array that square each element on the array, however I get the following error?

```
1) #square_array should square the elements in an array
     Failure/Error: expect(square_array([9,10,16,25])).to eq([81,100,256,625])

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
     # ./square_array.rb:3:in `block in square_array'
     # ./square_array.rb:2:in `each'
     # ./square_array.rb:2:in `square_array'
     # ./spec/square_array_spec.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.03363 seconds (files took 0.30161 seconds to load)
```

But the issue is only raised when is double digits numbers, The following Ruby code works with an array=[1,2,3]. Why it wont work with double digit numbers?

```
def square_array(array)
  array.each do |x|
      array[x-1] = x ** 2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of your error is this line,

```
array[x-1] = x ** 2
```

The [each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each) method calls the given block once for each element in self, passing that element as a parameter. So when you use [1,2,3] the `x-1` returns 0,1,2 which is ok. But when you use [9,10,16,25] it returns 8,9,15,24 which is definitely not the array index.

You can do it using `map` like this,

```
  def square_array(array)
    array.map{|x| x ** 2}
  end
```

To know more about how `map` works, take a look [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map).

Or you can use `each_with_index`,

```
  def square_array(array)
    array.each_with_index {|x, index| array[index] = x ** 2}
  end
```

If you really want to use only `each` (not recommended though)

```
  def square_array(array)
    i = 0
    array.each do |x|
      array[i] = x ** 2
      i+=1
    end
  end
```

Comment: I been asked to use the .each method  "Practice iterating over an array using the .each method."

Comment: You should see a "right" mark left side of my answer. Just click that "right" mark to accept the answer. @StevenAguilar